# How to define element ref with tsx in vue3 with rollup?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, rollup

I create a markdown editor component with vue3 and rollup and tsx, i also create an `example` with vue-cli and a `vite-example` with vite to test the editor.

[project address](https://github.com/hellomrbigshot/vue-next-m-editor)

But when i test the component in `example`, there are some bugs, for example, `onMounted` doesn't work, `ref.value` for element always be null.
Steps to reproduce

```
$ npm install
$ npm start
```

```
$ cd example
$ npm install
$ npm run serve
```

I use `@vue/babel-plugin-jsx` to compile jsx.

tsx code

```
setup () {
  const mTextareaRef = ref<HTMLTextAreaElement>()
  onMounted(() => {
    console.log('onMounted')
    console.log('mTextareaRef', mTextareaRef.value)
  })
  return () => (
    <div>
    ...
      <textarea
        ...
        ref={mTextareaRef}
      >
    </div>
  )
}
```

warning

```
[Vue warn]: Missing ref owner context. ref cannot be used on hoisted vnodes. A vnode with ref must be created inside the render function. 
  at <VueNextMEditor modelValue="# hello world" onUpdate:modelValue=fn > 
  at <App>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
const mTextareaRef = ref<InstanceType<HTMLTextAreaElement>>()

// ...
<textarea ref={mTextareaRef} {...attrs} />
```